# what is the gdbus API which i can call from c application to send command and receive data from pulse oximeter which uses Bluetooth HDP profile

Tags: bluetooth, bluez, gdbus

I am I am trying to communicate with the Pulse oximeter which uses Bluetooth HDP profile. I am writing a C application which uses gdbus API to communicate with BLUEZ stack. Can any one tell me which gdbus API can i use to send command and receive data. I have ported Bluez on raspberry-pi.

Answer (score 0):

The Bluez HDP apis are documented in the bluez source treee: src/doc/health-api.txt